# Personal loans and their tax consequences?

Tags: united-states, income-tax, loans, tax-deduction, personal-loan

In the year of 2014, I had some personal loans from friends, family members, ranging from $1000 to $10,000 for each loan.

As a result, my business net was negative because I used the loans to expense for my business.

Now filing the 2014 tax, do I need to report all those loans regardless the loan amount. If yes, how?

P.S.: I only have two types of income: rental and small online business. I am from CA.

Answer (score 4):

You need to report the interest expense, assuming the loans were for your business:

1. You need to report interest expense (only interest, principle is not an expense just as the loan proceeds are not income). The interest expense goes to the appropriate line on your Schedule C or E (depending on whether you used the loan for the online business or the rental).
2. People whom you borrowed from must also report the interest as income to them on their Schedule B. You cannot deduct the interest expense if they don't report it as interest income.

If you didn't take the loans for your business then the interest is not deductible. You don't need to report anything. People who lent you money still have to report the interest you paid to them as income on Schedule B.

If you paid no interest (free loan) or below/above market interest to a related party (family member), then the imputed interest is considered income to them and gift to you. They need to report it on their Schedule B, and depending on amounts - on a gift tax return. For $1K to $10K loans there probably will be no need in gift tax returns, the exemption is for $14K per year per person. If the imputed interest rules may apply to you, better talk to a licensed tax adviser on how to proceed.